# Trying to install ruby as system admin

Tags: ruby, rvm, tcsh, rbenv

I am managing a few linux clusters. I am trying to install ruby and some gems for all users, but I'm stuck somehow.

1. Easy version control/switching would be favorable.
2. All users should able to execute ruby AND gems without any problem. However, any capability for users to have control over installation/management of rubies and gems is not needed.
3. All users are using tcsh. Thus I guess RVM is not an option (I tried).
4. When I change ruby-related environment, I'd like to the change applied to all users, without them having them do something... I guess this might be accomplishable with /etc/csh.cshrc or /etc/skel/.tcshrc.
5. I don't want to touch group settings (while RVM forces it).

I'm currently considering using rbenv, but it is somewhat uncertain if it satisfies conditions above... I may abandon condition 1, but I have still no idea about getting gems working for all users...